# How i can have a filtered item on a listview with constant item position?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-actionbar, android-search

How i can have a `listView` with constant item position ?

Suppose you have a `listview` with a `searchbox` on `actionbar`. Now you want to filter the results and also want the `position` number of the item to be constant even after filtering.

The below code give me different position when i am searching on `listView`:

```
public class About extends ActionBarActivity {
      private ListView mainListView ;  
      private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
      SearchView searchview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //searchview = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
        String[] mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lstview_Content);
        String[] values= new String[5];
        for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
            values[i] = mTitles[i];
        }
        ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(values) );
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(About.this, R.layout.lstview_layout,R.id.rowTextView, planetList);
         mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
         mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
                int itemposition = position;
                String itemvalue = (String) mainListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :"+itemposition+"  ListItem : " +itemvalue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
         mainListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.about, menu);
        MenuItem searcehItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchview = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searcehItem);
        searchview.setQueryHint("ُُSearch");
        searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {

                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                mainListView.setFilterText(arg0);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ActionBarActivity` write :

```
int ID = 0;
```

In `onItemClick` write :

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i] == itemvalue)
    {
            ID = i;
        }
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Position :"+ID+"  ListItem : " +itemvalue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an index or position as part of your data model.

Comment: I need dynamically position .

Comment: Could you provide an example of your requirement please?